# Can Emacs keep track of files like BBEdit?

Tags: macos, emacs

To quote [a feature request for Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/101992-update-document-when-file-is-renamed-in-finder/):

> BBEdit has this functionality on OS X:
> - In BBEdit, open "myfile.txt"
> - In the Finder, rename "myfile.txt" to "myfile2.txt"
> - Now, in BBEdit, the document appears as "myfile2.txt", and saving the file updates "myfile2.txt"
>
> This is much better than the ST2 use case:
> - In Sublime Text 2, open "myfile.txt"
> - In the Finder, rename "myfile.txt" to "myfile2.txt"
> - Now, saving the document in ST2 silently creates a duplicate file "myfile.txt". This results in two slightly different versions of the same file in my workspace, causing headaches later.

A similar things happens with Emacs as with Sublime Text. So, I would love to find a way to make Emacs do what BBEdit is doing.

I searched Google, but I'm not actually sure what to search for here. Is there a specific term of art for this? Either way, I found nothing of interest.

Is there any existing way to do this? Or is it going to be quite complex? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276026/how-to-keep-track-of-file-locations-on-mac-os-x) says that the “Bookmarks” functionality of `NSURL` is what is being used here.

Comment: Some terms that may help with your search: "FSEvents" is the lower level API that OS X uses for watching files, there doesn't seem (from a quick search) to be any attempts at making emacs aware of it. Linux uses something similar called "inotify" that emacs also doesn't use, but the idea of interactions between inotify and emacs seems to have at least been mentioned on the internet before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `NEWS` file of latest Emacs trunk (unreleased)

> ***Support for filesystem notifications***.
>
> Emacs now supports notifications of filesystem changes, such as creation, modification, and deletion of files. This requires the `glib' API, or the 'inotify' API (on GNU/Linux systems only). On MS-Windows systems, this is supported for Windows XP and newer versions.

So the feature you are requesting for is possible for GNU/Linux and Windows users unfortunately it seems there is no support (in Emacs) for file notifications generated on OS X.

The code below should do what you want (though it has not been thoroughly tested). It requires the latest (unreleased) Emacs

```lisp
(require 'filenotify)
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar my-file-to-fd-hash (make-hash-table))

(defun my-file-notify-add-rename-watch (&optional file)
  (let ((file-name (or file buffer-file-name)))
    (when file-name
      (puthash file-name
               (file-notify-add-watch file-name
                          '(change)
                          'my-handle-file-change)
               my-file-to-fd-hash))))

(defun my-file-notify-rm-rename-watch (&optional file)
  (let* ((file-name (or file
                buffer-file-name))
         (fd (gethash file-name my-file-to-fd-hash)))
    ;; Stop watching the file
    (when fd
      (file-notify-rm-watch fd)
      (remhash file-name my-file-to-fd-hash))))

(add-to-list 'find-file-hook 'my-file-notify-add-rename-watch)
(add-to-list 'kill-buffer-hook 'my-file-notify-rm-rename-watch)

(defun my-handle-file-change (event)
  (let* ((fd (cl-first event))
         (action (cl-second event))
         (file (cl-third event))
         (renamed-to (cl-fourth event))
         (visiting-buffer (get-file-buffer file)))
    ;; Ignore events other than `rename` and also the `rename` events
    ;; generated due to emacs backing up file
    (when (and (eq action 'renamed)
           (not (backup-file-name-p renamed-to)))
      (message (format "File %s was renamed" file))

      ;; If file is not open ignore the notification
      (when visiting-buffer
        (with-current-buffer visiting-buffer
          (set-visited-file-name renamed-to))
        (my-file-notify-rm-rename-watch file)
        (my-file-notify-add-rename-watch renamed-to)))))
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks! Would it be a good idea to activate this for each file visited on a hook?

Comment: Hi, @NoahSlater, that code is just an example. It is not meant to used in init file as it is, you may want to modify it to according to your needs before using.

Comment: Also I have not tested it

Comment: Shouldn't this be a package-install or even rolled into main emacs?